# Create a pandas dataframe from a nested json file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested

I have the following json file:

```
{
    "data": {
        "start_date": "2022-10-01",
        "end_date": "2022-10-04",
        "cur": "EUR",
        "prizes": {
            "2022-10-01": {
                "coffee": 0.1448939471560284,
                "usd": 1
            },
            "2022-10-02": {
                "coffee": 0.14487923291390148,
                "usd":1
            },
            "2022-10-03": {
                "coffee": 0.1454857922753868,
                "usd": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a dataframe which looks like this, (so without the `usd` column):

```
              coffee  
2022-10-01  0.144894  
2022-10-02  0.144879  
2022-10-03  0.145486
```

**This is what I tried:**

```
path = r'C:\Users\Geo\Desktop\json_files\coffee.json'

df = pd.read_json(path)
df = pd.DataFrame(df['data']['prizes']['2022-10-01']['coffee']).T
print(df)
```

**This is what I received:**

```
   raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume your json file is loaded into dictionary as `data`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data']['prizes']).drop('usd').T
```

```
print(df)

              coffee
2022-10-01  0.144894
2022-10-02  0.144879
2022-10-03  0.145486
```

Comment: NB. [using `orient="index"` in the DataFrame`from_dict` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74123033/16343464) should be preferred to transposition, this is more efficient and avoids messing up with the dtypes (imagine usd was a string, coffee would become an object)

Comment: @mozway You are right, always learn something new from you :) and good selecting tips rather than `drop`.

Answer (score 4):

One option assuming `d` the input variable:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame
        .from_dict(d['data']['prizes'], orient='index')
        .drop(columns='usd', errors='ignore')  # or [['coffee']]
      )
```

output:

```
              coffee
2022-10-01  0.144894
2022-10-02  0.144879
2022-10-03  0.145486
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the json is stored in the variable `json`

```
json = {
    "data": {
        "start_date": "2022-10-01",
        "end_date": "2022-10-04",
        "cur": "EUR",
        "prizes": {
            "2022-10-01": {
                "coffee": 0.1448939471560284,
                "usd": 1
            },
            "2022-10-02": {
                "coffee": 0.14487923291390148,
                "usd":1
            },
            "2022-10-03": {
                "coffee": 0.1454857922753868,
                "usd": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following will do the work

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json['data']['prizes']).T.drop('usd', axis=1)

[Out]:

              coffee
2022-10-01  0.144894
2022-10-02  0.144879
2022-10-03  0.145486
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dic=json.load(path)
df=pd.DataFrame(dic)
print(type(df.loc['prizes']))
md=pd.DataFrame(df.loc['prizes'][0])
md=md.transpose()
del md['usd']
print(md)
```